# Controlling 120v line with a 12v switch on a different line

Tags: switches, relay, high-voltage, low-voltage

I have 10a 120v power sockets in my garage that currently doesn't have any switch on it and powers some overhead lights that I have plugged in. Separate to that, I have a 12v circuit powering various bits and pieces that is controlled via a 12v remote. I want it set up so that when I turn the remote on, it allows the power to the 120v sockets to pass and, when the remote is off, the power is cut. Effectively, the one 12v remote will be controlling both my 12v lights and my 120v lights.

Its my understanding that this should be quite easy and all that I need is a Relay. My trouble is knowing exactly which one should I use. I looked at a couple of Solid State Relays and they mentioned that they didn't handle sustained use well (headed up too much), even when underutilized. Hence I'm wondering what I should be looking at?

Comment: Due to the possibility of substantial inrush, derating the relay contacts for lights by 1/3 minimum is suggested so a 12Vdc 15A Relay would be one solution. (low cost Omron installed in a junction box.) from Mouser, Digikey or other

Comment: Some may also be automotive Relays https://www.digikey.ca/en/products/detail/panasonic-electric-works/JTV1S-TMP-12V/4692276 avail. at local auto-dept. stores then you might solder or get a socket and solder that to avoid overheating the contacts.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Not sure what you mean by "derating the relay contacts for lights by 1/3 minimum is suggested"... can you explain a little more?

Comment: 15A minus 1/3 = 10A more reliable rating

Comment: Ok so you are just talking about getting a relay that is oversized on the amperage front... so for my usage, if I got a 40a relay, it would be more than enough? Also given the "sustained" usage, should I be avoiding solid sate relays or is there a better type of relay for my usage?

Comment: Yes and Yes , no, although  SSR's have the advantage of Zero V switching (ZCS)

Comment: Ok given that, which of these would I use... https://www.amazon.com/INKBIRD-Solid-State-SSR-40DA-24-380V/dp/B00HV974KC or https://www.amazon.com/Yeeco-Contactor-Switching-electrical-switches/dp/B00MKWACVI.

Comment: Could you please furnish more details of your remote controlled board?